# How to dump the output of !dumpheap into a file, when the heap contains millions of objects?

Tags: windbg

Please, observe:

```
0:000> !dumpheap -stat
Statistics:
              MT    Count    TotalSize Class Name
000007fefa9c8c58        1           24 System.ServiceProcess.Res
000007fef99d3de8        1           24 System.Collections.Generic.GenericArraySortHelper`1[[System.DateTime, mscorlib]]
000007fef99cf8e8        1           24 System.Collections.Generic.GenericComparer`1[[System.Decimal, mscorlib]]
...
000007fef8f02090    47295    141585288 System.Char[]
000007fe9b1cbe20  1064155    229857480 Xyz.DataServices.Platform.BalanceTransactionForAccrualByOrg
000007fef8f06888    21401    238104833 System.Byte[]
000007fe9cd2efb8  1211503    358604888 Xyz.DataServices.Platform.AEBalanceTransaction
0000000000386b30 11759620   1701611244      Free
000007fef8e94918   777049   2352540408 System.Object[]
000007fe9c4370e8 10571587   2621753576 Xyz.DB.DL.HREEmployeeManager
000007fef8f00e08 131198125   1859306044 System.String
Total 163792779 objects
Fragmented blocks larger than 0.5 MB:
            Addr     Size      Followed by
...
```

Which means I have tens (hundreds?) of millions of objects on the heap. I would like to dump the information about them into a file.

So [How to redirect windbg command to a file without echoing the output on the windbg console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33532692/how-to-redirect-windbg-command-to-a-file-without-echoing-the-output-on-the-windb) tells me the approach, but is it the best we can get when we are talking about tens (hundreds?) of millions of rows?

I was wondering whether there is a programmatic API against which I could program to extract the data from the dump directly, rather than through WinDBG user interface. Or maybe there a plugin out there that already does it...

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37624824, because I tried to implement it for you

Comment: Much appreciated. Do not know why anyone would down vote it.

Comment: I also wonder about downvotes sometimes. I really tried to make it as minimal and complete as possible. Maybe someone thinks I should attach the dump?

Comment: @mark i think you can find some old src for sos (wdbgext style code that implements dumpheap )  on github at coreclr iirc  if you cant find it ill see if i cached the url

Comment: That's a lot of managers.  First obvious way to get ahead is to not wait so long before you create the minidump.  Second obvious way is conclude that Windbg isn't a great way to troubleshoot leaks and to use a decent .NET memory profiler.

Comment: I agree. But this is a production dump. I cannot profile a production machine. And this is not a leak, just bad code generating to many promotions to gen 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of the day I have written a powershell script to run a single debugger command using CDB. Then the output is saved to the file.

Here it is:

```
param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position = 0)][ValidateScript({Test-Path $_ })]
  $dump,
  [Parameter(ParameterSetName='cmd', Mandatory=$true, Position = 1)][ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
  $command,
  [Parameter(ParameterSetName='script', Mandatory=$true)][ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
  $scriptFile,
  [Parameter(ParameterSetName='init', Mandatory=$true)][ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()][switch]
  $init,
  [Parameter()]
  $imagePath,
  [Parameter()]
  $sosexPath = "e:\utils\sosex\64\sosex.dll",
  [Parameter()][switch]
  $ScanForImages,
  [Parameter()][switch]
  $NoSymbolServer,
  [Parameter()][switch]
  $NoExit
)
$dump = (dir $dump).FullName

$cdb = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x64\cdb.exe"
$InternalScriptFile = [io.path]::GetTempFileName()
$log = [io.path]::GetTempFileName()

if ($ScanForImages)
{
  $ImgScan = ".imgscan /l"
}

Set-Content $InternalScriptFile @"
.logopen `"${log}.init`"
.load $sosexPath
"@

if ($init)
{
  $CDBOutputDevice = "Out-Default"
  Add-Content $InternalScriptFile @"
.logclose
!bhi
"@
}
elseif ($command)
{
  $CDBOutputDevice = "Out-Null"
  Add-Content $InternalScriptFile @"
!lhi
$ImgScan
.logclose
.logopen `"${log}`"
$command
.logclose
"@
}
else
{
  $CDBOutputDevice = "Out-Null"
  Add-Content $InternalScriptFile @"
!lhi
$ImgScan
.logclose
.logopen `"${log}`"
"@
  Get-Content $scriptFile | Out-File -FilePath $InternalScriptFile -Encoding ASCII -Append
  Add-Content $InternalScriptFile @"
.logclose
"@
}

if ($NoExit)
{
  $CDBOutputDevice = "Out-Default"
}
else
{
  Add-Content $InternalScriptFile @"
q
"@
}

if ($NoSymbolServer)
{
  $symbols = "e:\Symbols"
}
else
{
  $symbols = "cache*e:\Symbols;srv*http://localhost:33417;srv*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols"
}
if (Test-Path $imagePath -PathType Container)
{
  $symbols = "$imagePath;$symbols"
}

&$cdb -cf $InternalScriptFile -z $dump -y $symbols | &$CDBOutputDevice
if (!$init -and !$NoExit)
{
  cat $log
}
```

Not ideal - I am open to improvements. But it works.